# Getting MSI exit code when installing remotely using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I use the following example to install some software on a remote computer

I would like to get the exit code back from the MSI so I can determine if successful or if not what the error was

I assumed $result would contain the information I need but I am obviously missing something

Ideas please?

```
$Result = Invoke-Command -computername MYREMOTEPC -ScriptBlock { Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList "/i C:\tmp\MYSOFTWARE.msi /quiet /norestart" -Wait -Passthru }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the `Start-Process -Passthru` command in `(...).ExitCode`:

```
$Result = Invoke-Command -computername MYREMOTEPC -ScriptBlock { 
 (
   Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList "/i C:\tmp\MYSOFTWARE.msi /quiet /norestart" -Wait -PassThru
 ).ExitCode
}
```

`-PassThru` instructs [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) to output a [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instance representing the launched process, and given that `-Wait` is also used, its `.ExitCode` property can be accessed right away.